# How to turn 2 for loops into pure recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I am wondering how I turn this piece of code so it only uses pure recursion, so no for or while loops and list comprehension.

```
def things(list1, list2):
    stuff = []
    for thing1 in list1:
        for thing2 in list2:
            if thing2 > thing1:
                stuff.append((thing1, thing2))
    return stuff
```

I have the base case set as

```
def things(list1, list2):
    if not (list1 and list2):
        return []
```

I know how to handle for one loop, but how to I manage the nested for loops?

Comment: add the sample input and expected outptut

Comment: `for / while` loops can loop into millions, recursion will fail after a few dozen calls.

Comment: @lenik huh? are you referring to the recursion limit? because that's about 1000, but the point is still relevant

Answer (score 1):

The first step for writing recursive functions would be to find the exit conditions. (The function should stop when the outer for loop ends).

Although for this sort of tasks `for/while` loops are way more efficient than recursion.

```py
def th(arr, list1, list2, index1, index2):
    if index1 == len(list1):
        return 
    elif index2 == len(list2):
        th(arr,list1,list2,index1+1,0)
    else:
        if list1[index1] < list2[index2]:
            arr.append((list1[index1], list2[index2]))
        th(arr, list1, list2, index1, index2+1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l1 = [1,3,5]
    l2 = [2,4]
    arr =[]
    th(arr,l1,l2,0,0)
    print(arr)
# arr : [(1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 4)]
```